# Translate curve horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, nodes, function

I drew this curve with pgfplots

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
          xmax=5,ymax=10,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=0:13,
          yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty,
          width=10cm,
          height=10cm,
          enlargelimits]
\addplot[blue,samples=100]  {(8*(1-exp(-x))^2)} node[above right] {\begin{tabular}{c} anharmonic\\oscillator \end{tabular}} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I'd like to make the same curve translated horizontally and "centered" for a value of `x`, for example, equal to `3`. And, perhaps, make sure that the "anharmonic oscillator" node is not clipped.

What do you recommend?

Comment: To move shift the curve you could simply use `(x-3)` wherever you used `x` to shift it by 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent your node from being clipped move it outside of the `axis`-environment. To remember the end point of the curve just use `coordinate(<name>)` instead of your `node`, then add `\node at(<name>)` after `\end{axis}`.

To shift the curve the simplest way would be to just redraw it shifted by a bit by using `(x-3)` instead of `x`.

To plot one curve only up to x values of 5 and the other up to 8 you have to change your `xmax` to 8 (or bigger), and specify a `domain` for your two `\addplot`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmax=8,ymax=10,
               axis lines=middle,
               restrict y to domain=0:13,
               yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty,
               width=10cm,
               height=10cm,
               enlargelimits]
    \addplot[blue,samples=100,domain=-5:5] {(8*(1-exp(-x))^2)} coordinate(end);
    \addplot[red, samples=100,domain=-2:8] {(8*(1-exp(-(x-3)))^2)};
  \end{axis}
  \node[above right,blue] at(end)
    {\begin{tabular}{c}anharmonic\\oscillator\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We are almost there! How do I extend the shifted curve to the right? I would need to extend it because it represents the Morse potential, and I have to highlight the asymptotic trend to the right

Comment: @user3713179 You set `xmax=5`. If you remove that you'll get it farther to the right.